# R - Error in decompose(series) : Not a graph object

Tags: r, time, series

I'm running a project I've done on Time Series Analysis in R. The data and the code are exactly the same as when I originally did this 3 months ago but I now get an error.

R code:

```
#create a time series dataset based on the moving average data
series <- ts(data_ma$demand_ma, start = c(2016,07,02), frequency = 52)

#decompose the time series, splitting between trend, seasonal and random.
decomp_series <- decompose(series)
plot(decomp_series)
str(data_ma)
```

## Result:

> Error in decompose(series) : Not a graph object

## Structure of the data:

```
str(data_ma)
'data.frame':   177 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ date_of_week_end: Date, format: "2016-07-02" "2016-07-09" ...
 $ demand_ma       : Time-Series  from 1 to 177: 617307 587475 608056 607321 602685
```

First few rows of the data. The data is 177 records long

[image: First few rows of the data. The data is 177 records long]

Any help would be really appreciated!!

Comment: You must have `igraph` loaded and there is a conflict. Use `sessionInfo()` and reset your session, see if that fixes it.

Comment: You absolute stunning person! Thank you so so much!